# CakePHP: FormHelper Timefield not inserting any data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, formhelper

The `formHelper` For time is not inserting data to the database:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|attendence_id|id   |in_time    |out_time|date.     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|15           |4    |00:00:30   |00:00:30|2014-04-12|
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

## My View

```
<div class="index">
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Employee In Time');
 echo $this->Form->input('Employee ID',array("name"=>"id"));
 echo $this->Form->input('In Time', array(
     'name' => 'in_time',
     'timeFormat' => '24',
     'type' => 'time',
     'selected' => '09:30:00'
 ));

 echo $this->Form->input('Out Time', array(
     'name' => 'out_time',
     'timeFormat' => '24',
     'type' => 'time',
     'selected' => '09:30:00'
 ));


 echo $this->Form->input('Date Insert in Y/M/D', array(
    'name' => 'date',
    'dateFormat' => 'YMD',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18 ));

 echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/users/add">New Employee</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_types">Attendance</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/add">Salary Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

## My Model

> ```
> class Attendence extends AppModel {
>
>
>     function add($data){
>         if (!empty($data)) {
>             $this->create();
>             if($this->save($data)) {
>                 return true ;
>
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

## My Controller

> class AttendencesController extends AppController {
>
> ```
> public function intime()
> {
>
>
>     if($this->Attendence->add($this->request->data)==true){
>         $this->redirect(array('action'=>'intime'));
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

## Please Help

Comment: what is `$this->request->data` when the form is submitted? Note that the add function is not really any different than calling save directly.

Answer (score 1):

**Take attention on CakePHP´s code convention:**

The first parameter of `echo $this->Form->create('Model');` is the model name, the view is related to. Replace your `Employee in Time` by your model´s name: `echo $this->Form->create('Attendence');`

I suggest to put your model´s code into the controller:

```
class AttendencesController extends AppController 
{  
    public function intime()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post','put'))
        {
            $this->Attendence->create();

            if($this->Attendence->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'intime'));
            }
        }     
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. Because for the date its orking fine and for other fields also. and for time in mentioned column name as **'name' => 'in_time',**

Comment: You are right. I have removed that note. What are the column names of in_time and out_time in the database? If they are in_time and out_time in your database, then use inTime and outTime in your View Helpers.

Comment: Honestly I think I am doing some mistake in MySQL... I declared the Columns **in_time** and **out_time** in my **Database** in the following way:- **Type-> Time, Collation*>UTF8(Bin)** is it correct?

Comment: I think, changing the collation in the datase seems not to be the problem. Better try to change the names in your input fiels `in_time` `out_time` to `inTime` and `outTime`.